# SpringXD: Can partitionPath and hdfs-dataset coexist?

Tags: spring-xd

I defined several streams, using the new `partitionPath` option so that files end up in per-day directories in Hadoop:

```
stream create --name XXXX --definition "http --port=8300|hdfs-dataset --format=avro --idleTimeout=100000 --partitionPath=dateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd/')" --deploy

stream create --name YYYY --definition "http --port=8301|hdfs --idleTimeout=100000 --partitionPath=dateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd/')" --deploy
```

All of the streams were created and deployed, except for `XXXX` up there:

```
17:42:49,102  INFO Deployer server.StreamDeploymentListener - Deploying stream Stream{name='XXXX'}
17:42:50,948  INFO Deployer server.StreamDeploymentListener - Deployment status for stream 'XXXX': DeploymentStatus{state=failed,error(s)=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate 'IntegrationConfigurationInitializer': org.springframework.integration.jmx.config.JmxIntegrationConfigurationInitializer}
17:42:50,951  INFO Deployer server.StreamDeploymentListener - Stream Stream{name='XXXX'} deployment attempt complete
```

Note that its data gets processed and deposited in avro format. And FWIW, where the other streams get put in `/xd/<NAME>/<rest of path>`, using the `hdfs-dataset --format=avro` combo results in files going to `/xd/<NAME>/string`

I re-defined it w/o the `partitionPath` option, and the stream deployed.

Do we have a bug here, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your XD topology? (singlenode or separate admin/containers). Is there anything in the container log(s)? What version of XD?

Comment: Admin node, four containers. 1.0.0.RELEASE. Just heard from our developers that they've run into this too. Containers are in Docker containers; need to figure out how to extract the logs. :-(

Comment: From a colleague: "...he should be able to do `docker logs container_id` to pull the logs...".

Answer (score 1):

The hdfs-dataset sink is intended for writing serialized POJOs to HDFS. We use the [Kite SDK](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/) kite-data functionality for this, so take a look at that project for some additional info.

The partitioning expressions for hdfs and hdfs-dataset are different. The hdfs-dataset follows the Kite SDK syntax and you need to specify a field of the POJO where your partition value is stored. For a timestamp (long) field the expression would look like this: `dateFormat('timestamp', 'YM', 'yyyyMM')` where timestamp is the name of the field, 'YM' is the prefix that gets added to the directory for the partition like `YM201411` and 'yyyyMM' is the format you want for the partition value. If you want a year/mont/day directory structure for the partition you could use `year('timestamp')/month('timestamp')/day('timestamp')`. There is some more coverage in the Kite SDK [Partitioned Datasets docs](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/guide/Partitioned-Datasets/).

For your example it doesn't make much sense to add partitioning since you are persisting a simple String value. If you do add a processor to transform the data to a POJO then partitioning makes more sense and we have some examples in the [XD docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/wiki/Sinks#hdfs-dataset-with-options).